# How can I convert this SQL SubQuery into a Join?

Tags: mysql

I am using SQL for the first time and can't seem to figure out how can I convert this query into a join. I want to do so, because I read this:
[Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query][1])

```
SELECT `bookings`.* FROM `bookings` WHERE `bookings`.`user_id` IN 
(SELECT `users`.`id` FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`phone` = 9999999999)
```

I want to find only those bookings whose users belong in the user table with a given phone number.

I tried using a join, but I don't understand what the possible condition of join should be.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would have tried to get you to try something first... oh, well, give a man a fish...

Comment: @Strawberry - What would that have been?

Comment: That would have been your best effort to date.

Comment: @Strawberry - I want to try that out.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Answer (score 1):

You need something like that:

```
    SELECT b.* FROM `bookings` b 
       INNER JOIN `users` u 
       ON b.user_id = u.id
    WHERE u.phone = 8860990440
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `bookings`.* FROM `bookings` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `bookings`.`user_id` WHERE `users`.`phone` = 9999999999
```